# Getting source map support for stack traces in meteor

Tags: meteor, babeljs

```
METEOR@1.4.2.5

"source-map-support": "^0.4.11",
"stack-trace": "0.0.9"
```

[stacktrace@0.0.9](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace)

[source-map-support@0.4.11](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support)

This config left no change, so I took out `source-map-support` and added `babel-plugin-source-map-support`.

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react","es2015","stage-0"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support"
  ]
}
```

And this gives me `The (source-map-support) Babel 5 plugin is being run with Babel 6.` even though [babel-plugin-source-map-support@0.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-source-map-support-for-6) says its "for-6".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up using `meteor add peerlibrary:stacktrace` without the npm stuff.